# absolute position child relative to scrolling grandparent

Tags: html, css

I have an ul and inside the li, I have a child div.  When I scroll inside the ul, I want the child div to remain positioned relative to the ul.  I am able to get the desired result using position static on the ul and li, but when I change the position of the ul and li to relative, it doesn't work.

```
  <ul class="grandparent">
    <li class="parent">
      <div class="child">
      Child
      </div>
      <div >
      <div>
      Spam
      </div>
      <div>
      Spam
      </div>
     <div>
      Spam
      </div>
     <div>
      Spam
      </div>
      </div>
    </li>
     <li>
      <div>
      Spam
      </div>
      <div>
      Spam
      </div>
     <div>
      Spam
      </div>
     <div>
      Spam
      </div>
      </div>
    </li>
    </ul>
```

Here is a link of the working copy
https://jsfiddle.net/4jhzfm1s/1/

So my question is, how can I get the desired effect while having the ul and li as relative positioned.

Answer (score 1):

If you make the parent scroll and keep only grandparent in relative, it works as expected:

```css
.grandparent {
  position: relative;
}
.parent {
  height: 100px;
  overflow: auto;
}
.child {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<ul class="grandparent">
  <li class="parent">
    <div class="child">
      Child
    </div>
    <div>
      <div>
        Spam
      </div>
      <div>
        Spam
      </div>
      <div>
        Spam
      </div>
      <div>
        Spam
      </div>
      <div>
        Spam
      </div>
      <div>
        Spam
      </div>
      <div>
        Spam
      </div>
      <div>
        Spam
      </div>
      <div>
        Spam
      </div>
      <div>
        Spam
      </div>
      <div>
        Spam
      </div>
      <div>
        Spam
      </div>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can also set top:auto and margin-top:50px , so you can have multiple elements set in absolute(alike fixed) example https://jsfiddle.net/4jhzfm1s/3/

Comment: there will be more li's so I have to keep the scrolling to the grandparent

Comment: @LunZhang **so you need to add an extra wrapper around ul** , else position : sticky; would do (or a js plolyfill) or dedicated script)  , but i believe CSS sticky  works actually only in Firefox (chrome i never know, once it does, then no more )

Comment: I'll try adding the extra wrapper around ul

Comment: its not working https://jsfiddle.net/4jhzfm1s/4/ somehow I think its impossible if I were to set the position of the ul and li to relative

Comment: @LunZhang Nop, li should not be relative, if it is, absolute children will follow the scroll of li. remove the relative from li, that was the point of my answer ;)

Comment: if I remove relative from li but keep relative in ul, it still doesn't work, that's wts been bothering me.  Shouldn't the child be following the ul not li?

Comment: @LunZhang did https://jsfiddle.net/4jhzfm1s/3/ worked ? or the snippet in question ? if not, which browser do you use ?

Comment: if i switch the overflow to grandparent, it doesn't work.  https://jsfiddle.net/4jhzfm1s/3/

Comment: @LunZhang nop ,cause then again, it scrolls with it ;), relative must not scroll, else absolute child follows the scroll , thus the purpose of that extra wrapper/inbrication to put appart elative and scroll

Answer (score 0):

So you want the .child to remain where it is no matter where you scroll right? If that's the case I would wrap the `ul` in a div and give that `position: relative` as follows:

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
}
.grandparent{
  height:100px;
  overflow:auto;
}
.child{
  position:absolute;
  top:50px;
  left:50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <ul class="grandparent">
    <li class="parent">
      <div class="child">
      Child
      </div>
      <div >
      <div>
      Spam
      </div>
      <div>
      Spam
      </div>
      <div>
      Spam
      </div>
      <div>
      Spam
      </div>
      <div>
      Spam
      </div>
      <div>
      Spam
      </div>
      <div>
      Spam
      </div>
      <div>
      Spam
      </div>
      <div>
      Spam
      </div>
      <div>
      Spam
      </div>
      <div>
      Spam
      </div>
      <div>
      Spam
      </div>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```